# Image of circles under $f(z) = \frac{z}{(z-1)^2}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

What is the image of circles $ |z| < 1$ under complex function $f(z) = \frac{z}{(z-1)^2}$?

$$f(z) = \frac{z}{z^2 + 1 - 2z} = \frac{1}{z+\frac{1}{z}-2}$$

$z+1/z$ is an ellipse and $z+1/z - 2$ is the ellipse shifted by 2 to the left along the Real axis. What will then become of $(z+1/z-2)^{-1}$?

Thank you.

Comment: Since you've written $f$ as $gk$ where $k(z)=\frac{z+z^{-1}}2$ and $g(z)=\frac 12\frac{1}{z-1}$, you could take things in steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for $|z|=1$,
$$
z+\frac1z-2=2\mathrm{Re}(z)-2\tag{1}
$$
maps the circle to the line segment $[-4,0]$. Thus, $\frac{z}{(z-1)^2}$ maps the circle to the ray $\left(-\infty,-\frac14\right]$.

If $\frac{z}{(z-1)^2}=w$, then
$$
z^2-\left(2+\frac1w\right)z+1=0\tag{2}
$$
For any $w$, the product of the two roots of $(2)$ is $1$. Thus, for any $w$ not on the ray, one root is inside the unit circle and one is outside. Thus, $\frac{z}{(z-1)^2}$ maps the inside of the circle to $\mathbb{C}\setminus\left(-\infty,-\frac14\right]$.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(e^{it}) = \dfrac{1}{2 (\cos(t)-1)}$$
traces out the ray $(-\infty, -1/4]$ on the real axis.  The image of the disk
is everything else in the complex plane.